# I'm having trouble with the warning of the undefined array key in my code

Tags: php

I tried several solution on the internet and it ended up not working. I'm still new at php so I apologize if this problem might be easy for you and hard for me.

```
if(isset($_POST['edit_Exam'])){

    $i = $_POST['exam_nameEdit'];
  

    $update_exam = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE examcategory SET e_Name  ='$i' WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."'");
    
     if($update_exam == true){
      ?>
        <script>
        alert("Data is updated!");
        window.location.href ="createExam.php";
        </script>
        <?php
       
    }
    else{
         ?>
        <script>
        alert("Data is not Inserted! \n Please try again");
        window.location.href="editExam.php";
        </script>
        <?php
    }

}
```

Comment: Either `$_POST['exam_nameEdit']` or - far more likely - `$_GET['id']` is not set. Given you have a `POST` request (for anything in `$_POST` to be set) it's most likely that `$_GET['id']` is not set. Perhaps you meant `$_POST['id']`?

Comment: How can I set $_GET['id'] because I tried setting it as $ref_id = $_GET['id'];  like this

if(isset($_POST['edit_Exam'])){
 $ref_id = $_GET['id']; 


    $i = $_POST['exam_nameEdit'];
  

    $update_exam = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE examcategory SET e_Name  ='$i' WHERE id='$ref_id' ");
    


Yet it shows a warning of no undefined array key 'id' on $_GET['id'];

Comment: Before you jump into guessing a solution, you have to check with yourself - where do you _expect_ the $id value to have come from? e.g. how does the browser send that value to PHP? Is it in the URL? Or is it in a form field? Or what? That will give you the information about how PHP should then try to read the value. Of course if you find that the browser isn't actually sending any ID value at all, then you'll need to go back and fix that first.

Comment: P.S. `<script>
        alert("Data is updated!");
        window.location.href ="createExam.php";
        </script>`...this is some horrible code from 20 years ago when people thought JavaScript popups were a good way to design a user interface. Just display a message on the page, or do an immediate redirect and display a message on the new page instead. Anything but making the user click on "ok" just to move on, and then having no way to retrieve the message which was just displayed. Yuk. I doubt you'll find any modern websites doing it like that anymore.

Comment: P.P.S. **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unparameterised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. If you learnt your current technique from a tutorial or book, please don't use that resource again.